# How use ssh-keygen to show either ECDSA or ecdsa-sha2-nistp256?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

When I do:

- `ssh -i id_rsa_something remoteuser@192.168.1.2`

appears:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ABCABC [fixed/changed].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

If I write `yes` I can get access to the remote server through SSH. So until here the SSH configuration for remote connections works as expected.

Now, just assuming in the `.ssh` directory exists many keys pairs for different remote/programs access. I want confirm what key/pair was used.

Therefore, now, If I do:

```
ssh-keygen -lf id_rsa_something.pub
```

appears:

```
2048 SHA256:XYZCYZ [fixed/changed] localuser@hostname.local (RSA)
```

The fingerprints are not the same (`SHA256:ABCABC` vs `SHA256:XYZCYZ`), seems the formats are different (the former includes `ECDSA`), but both show and include `SHA256:xxxx`. It is confuse in some way - an explanation about this is appreciated

I did do a research on Google and I tried:

- `ssh-keygen -E md5 -lvf id_rsa_something.pub`

And I got:

```
2048 MD5:e7:d1:... localuser@hostname.local (RSA)
```

Therefore trying with:

- `ssh-keygen -E ecdsa -lf id_rsa_something.pub`

appears:

```
Invalid hash algorithm "ecdsa"
```

Now, I can see at `.ssh/known_hosts` that was added:

`192.168.1.2 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNo...`

It was generated after the execution of the first command. Where `SHA256:ABCABC [fixed/changed]` and `AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNo...` are different

Even with:

- `ssh-keygen -E ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 -lf id_rsa_something.pub`

appears:

```
Invalid hash algorithm "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256"
```

With

- `ssh-keygen -E sha256 -lvf id_rsa_something.pub`

appears again

`2048 SHA256:XYZCYZ [fixed/changed] localuser@hostname.local (RSA)`

**Question:**

So is possible use `ssh-keygen -E` to *show* and get the *same* data shown such as either `ECDSA key fingerprint` or `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`?

Comment: **THOSE ARE DIFFERENT KEYS.** `ssh` when connecting to a not-yet-known host shows you the fingerprint of a HOST key, which is completely different from and not related in any way to any and all of your _user_ (aka _client_) key(s). If you want to see the fingerprint(s) of the host key, connect to the server, go to its configuration (typically `/etc/ssh` on Unix, if you have access) and run `ssh-keygen -l [-E $hash]` on the appropriate _host_ key file. Also the fingerprint _hash_ has nothing to do with the key _type_ (rsa, dsa aka dss now obsolete, ecdsa[-$various], ed25519).

Comment: Your comment has sense, can you consider to write how a solution? to mark it how valid?

Comment: I could not run it with the -E ecdsa but running it just like this:
"ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa" showed me this: 

256 SHA256:5JuiKSYoOXPpAanFHniutpQb9FYrompaW3gtoReQav4 localuser@hostname.local (ECDSA)